# How to fix my door

Tags: repair, wood, doors

[image]

I can't afford a new door so how can I repair it.

How much will it cost me to install a new door

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You may  want to replace your roommate when you replace your door. That said, cost estimates are off-topic here.

Answer (score 5):

In that condition, unless you get a steel cover plate to repair it, it's time to replace the door. Look for this item:

https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/RrkHH45lZUiGHlXLzZgy7w/o.jpg

Comment: I agree as the tools to repair that much damage can get fairly involved.

Comment: I agree as well and most attempted repairs will not be as strong as the original wood side rail of the door.

Answer (score 0):

Put little wooden screw or small nails/studs into the wooden door and apply the m-seal on it with mixture of wood powder, and colour it with same paint.

Note: Make sure m-seal and wooden mixture not go inside the latch/lock mechanism

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement? What's "m-seal"? (Please edit the info into your answer; thanks.)